# Why interpolating on Reactive Form does not return any value?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, interpolation, angular-reactive-forms

Console logging the form gives me null value when interpolation from Observable.

[component.html]

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="mainForm">
      <input formControlName="time"
              value="{{(time|async)}}">
    </form>
    <button (click)="log()">Log</button>
</div>
```

[component.ts]

```
mainForm: FormGroup;

time = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000);
  });


constructor(public fb: FormBuilder){
  this.mainForm = fb.group({
      time: null
    })
}


log(){
  console.log(this.mainForm.value)
}
```

Must i really use `.subscribe(value=> this.mainForm.patch(value))` ??

is there no other way? I hate unsubscribing.

**EDIT:**
Please assume `time` as a random example.

Comment: Please put the relevant code here - not only on stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is full of anti-patterns. You're using Reactive Forms along with value attribute on the input. You've initially set the value of the `formControlName` time as `null`. Unless you change it, it would be `null`. Although you're setting the `value` attribute of the input, it won't reflect on the form value.

A solution to this would be to `subscribe` to `time` and then explicitly call `setValue` on the `time` `FormControl`. Here's how you'd do it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `app.component.html`,
})
export class AppComponent {

  time = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000);
  });

  mainForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.mainForm = fb.group({
      time: null
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.time.subscribe(time => {
      this.mainForm.get('time').setValue(time);
    })
  }

  log() {
    console.log(this.mainForm.value)
  }

}
```

And then, in your template:

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="mainForm">
        <input 
      formControlName="time">
  </form>
  <button (click)="log()">Log</button>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgcab6?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: thanks i knew that... except that i read somewhere to not use subscribe whenever possible. please explain what do you mean by anti-pattern. the form is for users to update their details. I wrote the form following angular form guide. please assume `time` as something else. and NGRX will be in play.

Comment: The use of the 'value' attribute with a Reactive Form, is the anti-pattern here. You'd probably use it without a Reactive Form.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't mix template-driven and reactive forms! I also think your Observer stuff is a fiddle. I recommend to use timer instead. And yes you have to unsubsribe, please add it. Please also name observable with $

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="mainForm">
      <input formControlName="time">
    </form>

    <button (click)="log()">Log</button>
  </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  time$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(tick => new Date().toString())
  );

  mainForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder){
    this.mainForm = fb.group({
      time: new FormControl('')
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.time$.subscribe(t =>
      this.mainForm.get('time').patchValue(t)
    );
  }

  log(){
    console.log(this.mainForm.get('time').value)
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively with template driven form

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <form>
      <input [value]="time$ | async">
    </form>

    <button (click)="log()">Log</button>
  </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  time$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(tick => new Date()),
  );

  log(){ // removed argument 'event'
    this.time$.pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe( t => 
      console.log(t)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This was me not knowing how interpolation works on ReactiveForm.
It may display but will not pass the value to the form.
Thus it requires a subscribe. Thanks